# How to change value of a vector string to a different string value?

Tags: c++, vector

I was doing this exercise on writing a program that takes in words and prints the list of words without repetition. However, I am stuck when the question further asked to replace a word of choice(that I dislike) to "Bleep".

Here is the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    vector<string>words;
    string temp;

    while (cin>>temp)
        words.push_back(temp);

    cout << "Number of words: " << words.size() << "\n";

    for (int i = 0; i<words.size(); ++i)
        if(i == 0 || words[i-1] != words[i])
            cout << words[i] << '\n';



    return 0;
}
```

How can I add codes to change a string input by the user for example 'cute' to 'Bleep'? Thank you so much.

Comment: Just get that input word from the user, and add an `if/else` inside the `while` loop... BTW, your question kinda leaves the impression that you're asking us to do your homework for you.

Comment: you can use std::find if iterator return is not the end then you can use this iterator to change the value.

Comment: If you need list of words without repetition, u need to use set<T> instead of vector<T>.  Other than that, use answer from @acraig5075

Answer (score 3):

You can compare the input word with a list of prohibited words and continue according to whether the input word is in the list or not.

```
#include <algorithm>

vector<string> badWords = { "bad", "words", "for", "example", "cute" };

while (cin>>temp)
{
  if (std::find(badWords.begin(), badWords.end(), temp) == badWords.end())
    words.push_back(temp);
  else
    words.push_back("bleep");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just Change your

```
while (cin>>temp)
    words.push_back(temp);
```

this block to the following block:

```
vector<string> bad_words = { "beautiful", "nice", "sweet", "cute" };  // The badwords you have
while (cin>>temp){
    for(int i=0; i<bad_words.size(); i++){
        if(bad_words[i]==temp){
            temp="bleep";
            break;
        }
    }
    words.push_back(temp);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Am I right that by

> prints the list of words without repetition

you mean transform your initial vector of strings to the vector of unique strings? In such a case your algorithm is wrong. Look at the part

```
for (int i = 0; i<words.size(); ++i)
    if(i == 0 || words[i-1] != words[i])
        cout << words[i] << '\n';
```

This algoritm does not handle the cases where two or more repetitions are separated. For example

```
input: word1 word2 word3 word1 word1 word1
output: word1 word2 word3 word1
```

The output vector includes two equal words.